# Is this a good design for my library?

Tags: java

I am writing a client facing library and wanted to check if the below approach sounds reasonable? This library is a service that consumes HTML and creates a greeting card.

I feel writing Services and ServicesImpl may not be necessary and I only need ServicesImpl because the content in Services and ServiceImpl will be copied over. What would be a good design?

Consumed by user:

```
public class CardPrinter {
    public void create(String html) {
        Card Card = CardServiceImpl.createCard(html);
        // ..
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class CardService {
    Card createCard(String html);
}
```

Service impl:

```
public static class CardServiceImpl implements CardService {
    public static Card createCard(String html) {
        Card Card = Card.builder().content(html).build();
        return Card;
    }
}
```

Pojo:

```
public class Card {
    private String content;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us more about your domain in plain English? Poorly chosen classes and class names can often obscure even the simplest of problems.

Comment: @JanezKuhar - thank you for your feedback.  I have added a few more details.  The library takes an HTML input from the user and creates a greeting card. There are several intricacies which I have left out in lieu of the core aspect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I feel writing Services and ServicesImpl may not be necessary and I only need ServicesImpl because the content in Services and ServiceImpl will be copied over.

The main reason to have a `CardService` *interface* and a `CardServiceImpl` implementation class would be to be able to easily swap out the implementation that gets used, for example for testing purposes.

If you feel comfortable writing tests for `CardPrinter` using the real `CardServiceImpl` implementation, knowing that it might be harder to tell if a test failure is caused by a bug in `CardPrinter`, `CardServiceImpl` or a class used by the latter, then there is indeed no need for a `CardService` interface.

The general wisdom is to have the interface and inject either `CardServiceImpl` (in the real library) or a stub/mock CardService (in the unittests for `CardPrinter`).